# Get archived messages from xmpp server - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

I want to get messages from xmpp server.
I implemented some ideas but Neither of them work.

### First:

```
let iq = XMLElement.element(withName: "get_archive_user1") as? XMLElement
iq?.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "get")
iq?.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: "get_archive_user1")

let query = try? XMLElement(xmlString: "<query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:1'/>")

iq?.addChild(query!)

let with = XMLElement(name: "with", stringValue: "fattaneh123@jabb3r.org")

let set = XMLElement(name: "set", xmlns: "http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm")
let max = XMLElement.element(withName: "max", stringValue: "100") as? XMLElement
let before = XMLElement.element(withName: "before") as? XMLElement
set.addChild(max!)
set.addChild(before!)

query?.addChild(with)
query?.addChild(set)

xmppStream.send(iq!)
```

No message is received with above code.

### Second:

```
var iq1 = XMLElement.element(withName: "iq") as? XMLElement
iq1?.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "get")
iq1?.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: "pk1")
var retrieve = XMLElement(name: "retrieve", xmlns: "urn:xmpp:archive")
retrieve.addAttribute(withName: "with", stringValue: "fattaneh123@jabb3r.org")
var `set` = XMLElement(name: "set", xmlns: "http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm")
var max = XMLElement.element(withName: "max", stringValue: "100") as? XMLElement
iq1?.addChild(retrieve)
retrieve.addChild(`set`)
if let aMax = max {
    `set`.addChild(aMax)
}

xmppStream.send(iq1!)
```

**output:**

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="pk1" type="error" to="fattaneh1234@jabb3r.org/4b27ae0b-8c57-4185-ab27-09f721847911"><error type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></service-unavailable></error></iq>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [service unavailable error in openfire message archive management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237997/service-unavailable-error-in-openfire-message-archive-management)

Comment: @andesta.erfan I don't use openfire

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: hi @FattanehTalebi I use ejabberd server. if known answer for how to get archived messages from xmpp server using Swift  means pls post your answer in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749713/issue-on-retrieve-the-xmpp-archived-message-from-ejabberd-serverchat-history)