# service unavailable error in openfire message archive management

Tags: ios, openfire, xmppframework

I am using monitoring plugin 1.6.0 with openfire 4.2.0.

Following is the screenshot of archive settings on openfire admin Console.

[image]

also following is the screenshot of plugins I am using with this.
[image]

**My Issue**

as you can see the plugin is installed.
but when I am trying to fetch chat history with following code : I am getting service unavailable response.

```
func fetchChatHistoryFromServer(completionHandler completion: @escaping FetchChatHistoryCompletionHandler) {

    let iq = DDXMLElement(name: "iq")
    iq.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "set")
    iq.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: UserManager.shared.activeUser.jid)

    let query = DDXMLElement(name: "query")
    query.setXmlns("urn:xmpp:mam:2")
    query.addAttribute(withName: "queryid", stringValue: XMPPManager.shared.xmppStream.generateUUID)

    let x = DDXMLElement(name: "x")
    x.setXmlns("jabber:x:data")
    x.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "submit")


    let field = DDXMLElement(name: "field")
    field.addAttribute(withName: "var", stringValue: "FORM_TYPE")
    field.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "hidden")
    let fieldValue = DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "urn:xmpp:mam:2")
    field.addChild(fieldValue)
    x.addChild(field)
    query.addChild(x)
    iq.addChild(query)
    //let xmppResultSet = XMPPResultSet(max: 2000)
    Logger.log(iq)
    didFetchChatHistoryCompletionBlock = completion
    xmppMessageArchivingManagement?.retrieveMessageArchive(withFields: [iq], with: nil)
}
```

OutPut Log :-

```
<iq type="set" id="dev60@dev.myapp.com">
    <query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:2" queryid="20B07616-12BC-41BB-9DE6-F0F6A74951A5">
        <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
            <field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden">
                <value>urn:xmpp:mam:2</value>
            </field>
        </x>
     </query>
</iq>
```

Response :--

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="7BED0303-46E3-40D4-BE47-543BB7810F66" to="dev60@dev.myapp.com/a3lb3jaw9g">
<query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:2" queryid="80D6D753-B2BF-4626-84B5-C216D4B94996">
    <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
        <field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden">
        <value>urn:xmpp:mam:2</value>
        </field>
        <iq type="set" id="dev60@dev.myapp.com">
            <query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:2" queryid="20B07616-12BC-41BB-9DE6-F0F6A74951A5">
                <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
                    <field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden">
                        <value>urn:xmpp:mam:2</value>
                    </field>
                </x>
            </query>
        </iq>
    </x>
</query>
<error code="503" type="cancel">
    <service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></service-unavailable>
</error>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

openfire do not support `urn:xmpp:mam:2` you have to use `urn:xmpp:mam:1` instead.
you have to change it in XMPPMessageArchiveManagemnt class.
just go to XMPPMessageArchiveManagement class .in line of 20 it said 
`/** 'urn:xmpp:mam:2' */ extern NSString *const XMLNS_XMPP_MAM;`.
just hold command and click on XMLNS_XMPP_MAM after that change `urn:xmpp:mam:2` to `urn:xmpp:mam:1`

Comment: have tried ------- --- <iq type="set" id="dev60@dev.myapp.com"><query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1" queryid="76F5796F-FD5B-41A4-B74B-BB172599F40A"></query></iq> ---------------- but same result -----------<error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></service-unavailable></error>

Comment: Also tried -------- <iq type="set" id="dev60@dev.myapp.com"><query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1" queryid="6DB86285-06F1-49C8-9EE0-77A29AE95942"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden"><value>urn:xmpp:mam:1</value></field></x></query></iq>---------------------- but no luck either....

Comment: @PawanJoshi i think you did not specify the "with" field.your outgoing IQ should be something like this `<iq type='set' id='juliet1'>
  <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:2'>
    <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
      <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'>
        <value>urn:xmpp:mam:2</value>
      </field>
      <field var='with'>
        <value>juliet@capulet.lit</value>
      </field>
    </x>
  </query>
</iq>` the JID should not have any xmpp domain or resource just use the local part

Comment: tried following three -------- <iq type="set" id="dev60"><query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1" queryid="CB4F2F57-3F61-478B-BF84-0BC1617B0AAC"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="with"><value>dev64@dev.myapp.com</value></field><field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden"><value>urn:xmpp:mam:1</value></field></x></query></iq> ------ but same result.

Comment: ------------------- <iq type="set" id="dev60"><query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:2" queryid="3CE3D171-C26B-4B2C-A7A7-AA3DD52D2650"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="with"><value>dev64@dev.myapp.com</value></field><field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden"><value>urn:xmpp:mam:2</value></field></x></query></iq>

Comment: <iq type="set" id="dev60"><query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:0" queryid="BF9D538B-BA45-48C5-9B76-2E8FC501BD27"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="with"><value>dev64@dev.myapp.com</value></field><field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden"><value>urn:xmpp:mam:0</value></field></x></query></iq>

Comment: @PawanJoshi BECAUSE YOU ARE USING MAM:2 . just go to XMPPMessageArchiveManagement class .in line of 20 it said `/** 'urn:xmpp:mam:2' */
extern NSString *const XMLNS_XMPP_MAM;`. just hold command and click on `XMLNS_XMPP_MAM` after that change `urn:xmpp:mam:2` to `urn:xmpp:mam:1`

Comment: thou art a saviour ... I bow to you in gratitude ... :) please update your answer so that I can accept it.